# Visual Studio 2010 - Partially Publish Web Site?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, publish

I just completed a website that is image heavy and I'm publishing the site to an FTP server. The publish time takes ~5 minutes. Is there a way for me to configure which file types get published? I'd like to push out changes only if the file extention is: (.config, .aspx, .cs, .asmx, .js, .html, .css, .master).

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try using the Copy-Web-Tool - there you may choose single files or only updated files aso. In any way there is a big difference between choosing "publishing" or "copying". publish -> you may choose to precompile your sourceCode files. copy -> you will have to copy the source code files too - as they are compiled on the very first call of the according aspx file.

Comment: Where is the copy-web-tool found?

Comment: Right click on your project element in your solution explorer - "copy Web". In case you can't find it there you may have created your website by choosing "file - new project - web - asp.net application" rather than "file - new website". unfortunatelly this makes a difference in where to find some options.

Comment: Very helpful. Never knew that was there. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the publish process publishes the whole website.

Publish it on your local computer first and then use an FTP tool (Filezilla, CoreFTP...) to selectively upload your files to the server.

Comment: thanks! Publishing locally seems like a decent alternative. It seem silly that and IDE like VS doesn't let you control this though...

Comment: @Quickfire55 It does so as it provides options for fixed naming and strong naming on precompiled assemblies. The handling of references would be problematic in strong type updatable publish. Anyhow lets hope that they provide this facility in their future releases :)

Comment: Supposedly the new 2012.2 update should allow you to publish specific files -- http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2013/May/10/Publish-Individual-Files-to-your-Server-in-Visual-Studio-20122 -- I haven't figured out how to get it to work yet: the context menu option isn't there but the shortcut `ALT+P, ALT+P` is

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately No, it is not possible. Publish operation is either-all-or-none operation.

Even though, I sometimes only copy the DLL assembly (from bin directory to IIS website folder) if the change is only in the code-behind files and the markup/images/other-content have no changes.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the `Build Action` for whatever you don't want published to `None`

These won't get copied to the deployment directory

I have just confirmed that it works (I tested on a MVC3 site)

so you'll have to change the setting for each file you want to exclude but you can change the setting of multiple at one time and folders can't be excluded

[image]

Comment: then he can select the 1000 images and set them all to `None`. Select the first, shift-select the last and change the option. It gets more tedious if there are many folders though

Comment: this will only work for a `Web Application` not a `Web Site` - the option isn't available in a web site