# how to upload only modified files not all files to server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am using vs 2010 web

I want to know that:

how to upload only modified files/file to server instead of upload full project.

if a made a small change in a aspx file and want to see how it look like live . then vs 2010 upload each time all pages/files to server and it take time.

how to solve it

Thank you

js

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2010 - Partially Publish Web Site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520196/visual-studio-2010-partially-publish-web-site)

Answer (score 0):

Right click that file and Select "Check-in".