# Visual Studio - Publish single file in Web Site Project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ftp, publish, visual-studio-extensions

Similar question -- [Visual Studio 2010 - Partially Publish Web Site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520196/visual-studio-2010-partially-publish-web-site)

I would like to push single files up from a plain **Web Site** project (not Web App), like you can in Sublime Text 2 ([plugin](https://github.com/NoxArt/SublimeText2-FTPSync)) with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+U</kbd>.

Supposedly [this is now available as a context-menu option with the 2012.2 update](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2013/May/10/Publish-Individual-Files-to-your-Server-in-Visual-Studio-20122), but even though the shortcut chord <kbd>ALT+P, ALT+P</kbd> shows in the customize keyboard settings, it's not available in the context menu.

Full scenario -- attempting to push PHP files to a LAMP stack via FTP (assume same as static img/js/css files), editing PHP with [this PHP extension](http://www.devsense.com/products/php-tools).  I've already configured the Publish Profile with the correct FTP credentials; I have successfully tested a full "Publish Web Site" on the project, so I don't understand [why the context menu options aren't showing.](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2013/May/10/Publish-Individual-Files-to-your-Server-in-Visual-Studio-20122#127707)

Comment: Seems that I can at least get the context-menu options if I create a Web Deploy profile (just save, not perform).  But trying to publish it individually just hangs on the "preparing to publish files" step.